# Azure Data Factory Python SDK - Convert PipelineResource to JSON

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-python-sdk

I am creating Azure Data Factory pipeline using Python SDK (`azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.PipelineResource`). I need to convert `PipelineResource` object to JSON file. Is it possible anyhow?

I tried `json.loads(pipeline_object)` , `json.dumps(pipeline_object)` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to convert PipelineResource object to JSON file. Is it possible anyhow?

You can try the following code snippet as suggested by [mccoyp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/25081):

You can add a default argument to `json.dumps` to make objects that are not JSON serializable into `dict`

```
import json
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import Activity, PipelineResource

activity = Activity(name="activity-name")
resource = PipelineResource(activities=[activity])

json_dict = json.dumps(resource, default=lambda obj: obj.__dict__)
print(json_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
# Create a copy activity
act_name = 'copyBlobtoBlob'
blob_source = BlobSource()
blob_sink = BlobSink()
dsin_ref = DatasetReference(reference_name=ds_name)
dsOut_ref = DatasetReference(reference_name=dsOut_name)
copy_activity = CopyActivity(name=act_name,inputs=[dsin_ref], outputs=[dsOut_ref], source=blob_source, sink=blob_sink)

#Create a pipeline with the copy activity

#Note1: To pass parameters to the pipeline, add them to the json string params_for_pipeline shown below in the format { “ParameterName1” : “ParameterValue1” } for each of the parameters needed in the pipeline.
#Note2: To pass parameters to a dataflow, create a pipeline parameter to hold the parameter name/value, and then consume the pipeline parameter in the dataflow parameter in the format @pipeline().parameters.parametername.

p_name = 'copyPipeline'
params_for_pipeline = {}

p_name = 'copyPipeline'
params_for_pipeline = {}
p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[copy_activity], parameters=params_for_pipeline)
p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
print_item(p)
```